# Cannot read my database from data/data/<package name>/databases folder

Tags: assets

I have a problem when the application is launched for the first time in emulator. When I run the application, the database file that is in my assets folder should copy and read.Ok it copies the database file WITH database.sqlite.journal file as well (Strange for me and Why?). But the application crashes then.

After that I always have to delete those both files from databases folder and pull the database file there. After that it runs smoothly until I use the same emulator.

Why is it happening so? My code for the databasehelper class is below. Am I doing something wrong?

```
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing-database already exists
        Log.i("DB....", "database available....");

    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of the application so we will be able to overite the database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error Copying database");
        }
        Log.i("DB..", "database created.....");
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDataBase = null;
    try {
        String Path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("CheckDb", "DB not found");
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDataBase != null) {
        checkDataBase.close();
    }

    return checkDataBase != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from local assets-folder to the just created empty
 * database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local database as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // path to just created empty db.
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream.
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    Log.i("Database", "New database is being copied to device!");

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // Close the stream.
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    Log.i("Database", "New database has been copied to device!");

}

/**
 * Open the database
 * 
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, 0);
    Log.i("DB....", "database opened....");
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (mInstance != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check your variables

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/PACKAGENAME/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "DBNAME.db";
```

Comment: Everything is correct Oli. I explain more clearly again.

I explain more clearly again. first time while installing the application to new device;
-> It shows error like cannot open db file.
-> Run again, it says no such table found.
-> Then delete db files from data/data/<package>/databases/
-> And pull the db file there manually.
-> Then it starts perfectly.